# Contradiction while using the convolution sum for a non-LTI system

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, convolution, linear-systems

In a recent quiz, we were given the following problem:

> The cascaded LTI systems $\mathcal{T}_1$ and $\mathcal{T}_2$ respectively have impulse responses $h_1[n]=\delta[n+3]$ and $h_2[n]=\delta[5−n]$. What is the output when the input is $x[n]=n$, i.e., find $y[n]=\mathcal{T}_2\{\mathcal{T}_1\{x[n]\}\}$.

I am primarily confused about the "LTI-ness" of the system and at a contradiction; given the second stage to be LTI (assuming that for a system to be LTI as a whole, all its stages/subsystems must also be LTI). Thus, we can say that a sub-system with  $h \lbrack n \rbrack = \delta \lbrack 5 - n\rbrack$, i.e. $y \lbrack n \rbrack = x \lbrack 5 - n\rbrack$ should be LTI, which already seems to be false. To prove that, I considered the following convolution sum: $$\tilde{y} \lbrack n \rbrack = \displaystyle{\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} x \lbrack k \rbrack \delta \lbrack 5 - n + k \rbrack} = x \lbrack n-5 \rbrack \ne x \lbrack 5-n \rbrack = y \lbrack n \rbrack$$

And this is a contradiction since, after the convolution, the output doesn't match the original output with which we started.

Also, I realized that interestingly, the convolution always gives a result that corresponds to an LTI system (as in the case above too: $y[n]=x[n−5]$ is LTI whereas $y[n] = x[5-n]$ is not).

Also, since $\delta[n]$ is even, any non-LTI system's impulse response, for example, $\delta[1−n]$, will equal $\delta[n−1]$ which corresponds the impulse response of an LTI system. This explains why I am getting LTI characteristics after the convolution. This is interesting too since in either way the impulse response implies delaying the signal by 1 (in the current example).

And so did the impulse response $\delta[5-n]$ stated in the quiz question just qualitatively imply a delay of 5, and is, technically, not the exact description of the underlying system?

So, in summary, I have the following two doubts:

1. Is the convolution sum only true for the output relation of an LTI system? If so, then can it be used to prove non-LTI-ness of a system in the same manner as above?
2. Is the quiz question incorrect?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two misunderstandings here. First, you seem to think that if a system's impulse response is $h[n]=\delta[5-n]$, then its response to an input sequence $x[n]$ equals $x[5-n]$. This is not the case. And second, you seem to think - or at least you're not sure about it - that a system with a response $x[5-n]$ to an input is LTI, and hence is completely specified by its impulse response. That's also not true.

The system $y[n]=x[5-n]$ is linear but it is *not* time-invariant. In order to prove this you just have to show that the response to $x[n-k]$ for some integer $k$ does not equal $y[n-k]$, where $y[n]$ is the response to $x[n]$. This is straightforward to show, and I leave this proof up to you.

An LTI system with impulse response $h[n]=\delta[5-n]$ delays its input by $5$ samples: $y[n]=x[n-5]$, as you've shown yourself in your question. This is also immediately obvious from the fact that $\delta[n]$ is an even sequence, i.e., $\delta[n]=\delta[-n]$, and, consequently, $\delta[n-k]=\delta[k-n]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out my misconceptions! I still have one doubt: why would the system $y[n] = x[5-n]$ not have an impulse response of $\delta[5-n]$, or do we just avoid using the term "impulse response" for non-LTI systems? Because this is what is still confusing me.

Comment: @PranshuMalik: The response of that system to an impulse $x[n]=\delta[n]$ is indeed $\delta[5-n]$. So in that sense this is its impulse response. But this impulse response does not characterize the system in such a way that the responses to *all* possible input signals can be computed from it (via the convolution sum). But that's what we usually mean by referring to the *impulse response* of a (LTI) system.

Comment: Ahh. I see my mistake completely now. Thanks again :)

Comment: if $y[n] = x[5-n]$ does not obey convolution sum so please show the convolution sum that $y[n] = h[n]$ produce what ?

Comment: (produces) a joke may be ;-)))

Answer (score 1):

You've some troubles about the LTI property and the impulse response. First of all let me give you the answer to your quiz question.

Given two LTI systems $\mathcal{T}_1$ and $\mathcal{T}_2$ with impulse responses :

$$h_1[n] = \delta[n+3]$$
$$h_2[n] = \delta[5-n] = \delta[n-5]$$

you can compute the output of the cascade $$y[n] = \mathcal{T}_2 \{ \mathcal{T}_1 \{ x[n] \} \} $$ for the input signal $x[n] = n$ as :

$$ y_1[n] = \mathcal{T}_1 \{ x[n] \} \implies y_1[n] = n \star \delta[n+3] = (n+3) $$

and

$$ y_2[n] = \mathcal{T}_2 \{ y_1[n] \} \implies y_2[n] = (n+3) \star \delta[n-5] = (n-2) $$

so your output is $$y[n] = n-2$$

Note that $h_2[n] = \delta[5-n]$ and $h_2[n] = \delta[n-5]$ are the **same** systems, and yield the same output.

Note again that both systems are declared to be LTI and are given their respective impulse responses $h_1[n]$ and $h_2[n]$ , therefore their cascade will also be LTI and furthermore the output does not depend on the ordering of the systems; i.e.

$$y[n] = \mathcal{T}_2 \{ \mathcal{T}_1 \{ x[n] \} \} = \mathcal{T}_1 \{ \mathcal{T}_2 \{ x[n] \} \}  $$

Now coming to your own questions:

1- You cannot use convolution sum to deduce LTI property. You cannot form a convolution sum if the system is not already LTI.

2- The question seems ok:

Note: your claim that $ h[n] = \delta[5-n] $ , signifies a non-LTI system is wrong...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But I'm still wondering that If $y[n] = x[-n] $ is non-LTI, then why isn't $y[n] = x[5-n]$ also non-LTI?

Comment: $y[n] = \mathcal{T} \{x[n]\} =  x[-n]$ is a general **system input-output** definition which is *time-varying* therefore not LTI and does not have an impulse response $h[n]$. On the other hand, the impulse response $h[n] = \delta[m-n]$ signifies (by definition!) an LTI system whose input output relation is $y[n] = h[n] \star x[n] = \delta[m-n] \star x[n] = x[n-m]$ where there is no conradiction...

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Why doesn't $y[n] = x[-n] $ not have an impulse response? If your input is $\delta[n] $, then the output will be $h[n] = \delta[-n] $. And I understand that this response will not help us with characterizing the system's output for a general input. But, I don't really understand why $y[n] = \delta[m-n] $ is LTI. This is, I think, the root of my doubts

Comment: you have a problem with the concept of **system** and **impulse response**. Please consult a book on Signal's and Systems chapter one and two.

Comment: Yes, I've read through my course notes on these topics. I'll be very grateful if you could redirect me to a specific resource or tell me a particular topic to search for. The notes did cover why time reversal is time-varying, from which I came to the extension that any inversion of index, that is, making $y[n] = x[n-K]$ into $y[n] = x[K-n] $ will result in a time-varying system. And as far as i understand, impulse response of a system is literally an impulse's response. So regardless of the system's linearity or time-invariance, an impulse response has to be defined for any system.

Comment: **systems** are defined via I/O $$y[n]=T\{x[n]\}$$ may have properties: *linearity*, *time-invariance*, *causality*, *stability*, *invertibility*, *memoryless* etc. Those systems which are *linear* and *time-invariant* are called as **LTI** and they are fully characterised by their **impulse responses** $$h[n] = T\{ \delta[n]\}$$ such that their output for arbitrary input is given by the **convolution sum** as $$y[n]= T\{x[n]\} = \sum_k x[k] h[n-k] = x[n] \star h[n]$$ Eventhough you can compute $h_0[n] =T\{\delta[n]\}$ for every system, it's only LTI that enables convolution sum for output...

Comment: Exactly. So I have two simple questions: 1. Is $y[n] = x[5-n]$ LTI? 2. Is the impulse response for the system above $\delta[5-n]$ ? And if so, then the convolution sum with $ x[n]$ doesn't match the input-output relation in part 1 (above). Can this be a valid proof for non-LTI-ness of the system?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92404/discussion-between-pranshu-malik-and-fat32).

Comment: The system $y[n] = x[5-n]$ is not LTI, therefore it does not have an **impulse response** function of the form $h[n]$; hence the *convolution* argument is meaningless, thus it's not a valid argument to prove LTI property.

Comment: Makes sense yes. I fully understand that now. Thank you!